# Give form a CSS class using simple_form_for

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, class, simple-form

Here's what I've tried, and the `simple_form_for` call ignored my class setting.

```
# Rails code in view:
<%= simple_form_for @admin_artist, :class => 'foobarbaz' do |f| %>

# Renders:
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/artists" class="simple_form new_admin_artist" id="new_admin_artist" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

this would work

```
<%= simple_form_for @admin_artist, :html=> { class: 'foobarbaz' } do |f| %>
```

Comment: Where did you find that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `:html` like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @admin_artist, :html => { role: 'form', class: 'foobarbaz' } do |f| %>
```